# UIControlEvents and subclassing UIControl

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have a UIControl subclass for a custom slider type control (one that behaves differently from UISlider). At the moment I use my own target and action variables to send a message to the target whenever the slider value changes. But this doesn't play nice with Apple's UIControlEvent constants. I wasn't sure if I should use these, and if so, where can I put my custom "value changed" detection?

I overrode beginTrackingWithTouch: and continueTrackingWithTouch: to return YES but the action is never dispatched.

Comment: What do you mean you "use your own target?"?

Comment: I meant that I had my own active and action ivars in the class, instead of using what UIControl provides.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Every time the value changes you call `[self sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged]` and the control will handle the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are passing touchesBegan and other inherited methods to super class.